# 'date_sub' is not defined pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use date_sub in the below expression but getting error

```
def get_dateid_1(datetime):
    datetime = str(datetime).rsplit(" ")[0]
    return datetime

df123 = F.expr(date_sub(get_dateid_1(datetime.now())), 1)
print(df123)
```

ERROR:

> date_sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'days' Traceback
> (most recent call last): TypeError: date_sub() missing 1 required
> positional argument: 'days'

though have given the days, it gives me the error

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Try: `F.expr(date_sub(get_dateid_1(datetime.now()),1))`

Comment: @ScootCork> i tried, it says "TypeError: Column is not iterable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains many errors and I'm not sure I quite understand what you want to do.

[`expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) takes a string expression but you're passing a "column". It should be like this:

```
df123 = F.expr(f"date_sub({get_dateid_1(datetime.now())}, 1)")
print(df123)

# Column<b'date_sub(((2021 - 1) - 27), 1)'>
```

Or if you want to use Pyspark functions (`lit` to pass the date returned by the function) :

```
df123 = F.date_sub(F.lit(get_dateid_1(datetime.now())), 1)
print(df123)

# Column<b'date_sub(2021-01-27, 1)'>
```

However, if your intent is to substract one day to the current date, you should be using the Spark builtin function [`current_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.current_date):

```
df123 = F.date_sub(F.current_date(), 1)
print(df123)

# Column<b'date_sub(current_date(), 1)'>
```

Comment: Also using timedelta function helped. Figured out timedelta fucntion helps in specifying hours, days and months. something like this.
```currentdate = estnow() 

currentdateID = ((currentdate) - timedelta(hours=20, minutes=00))```